# Data Visualisation For Scheduling

Tags: info-visualisation, dates

What is the best method for defining a scheduler visualisation (and editor)? Basically I think I am looking for something similar to a Gantt chart (not quite the same) where I have a start and end date. However it isn't as simple as that, as I have 2 start and end dates for the system (A primary and a secondary which will always be less than or equal to the primary date range).

Its almost like I am looking for a gantt chart with a range slider in between the extents of the primary dates. From a user experience point of view would this work? (The two items are very closely related). Do you have any other suggestions for better ways of doing this?

Comment: you need to give us more info to work with.  Are we talking tens of date ranges or hundreds?  Does moving a secondary start date always affect the primary end date?  What drawbacks in your proposed solution do you think our suggestions might solve?

Comment: It would also help to know what data you're dealing with, just in terms of being able to map it in my brain. I might be able to refer back to a project I once did if I don't have to think in abstracts.

Comment: What is the task that the user is performing here?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have a kind of flexible-time/core-time distinction.  Try something like this:
[image]

Comment: For a live example of this, check out hipmunk: http://www.hipmunk.com/results?to=new+york&s=sh9lzffd0mw&from=amsterdam